# How do I use restful services in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Hi i'd like to get all the data from the employees table
in a way that it refreshes using restful services if that makes sense.
i'd like the result in json and then put into a text area or something.
 select * from emp

Having trouble understanding restful webservices withing oracle apex particularly.

bonus: if you guys have a way to use angular js in oracle apex would be amazing especially http requesting a table.

Comment: you can define restful services in apex and also in oracle rest data services - pick one. I'd say Oracle REST Data Services for sure if it's installed and configured in your APEX install. What version of APEX are you running?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith apex 5.1

Comment: Btw I'd like to know how to use it in apex on the web first

Comment: There's a restful services page in the apex admin console - go there and build your restful service. And Google 'oracle apex' and 'angular' - there's stuff out there